# how to $_GET when it has a ' in the text

Tags: php, mysql

I pass a variable called txt from one query on a web page to another web page using

```
    <?php echo $_GET['txt'];?>
```

the problem some time the text will have a word like don't in it.  the (') causes things to just stop.  I need to output the variable as read from the database which would include any text that was in the field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `$_GET` you should use [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) and [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).

Comment: thank you but when passing don't on the page using even this echo  htmlentities($_GET['txt'])  still stops the page at don...

Comment: Did you try the urlencode and urldecode?

Comment: Yes and same thing when it comes to any word with a ' in it.. IE; Don't  will display  Don and then the rest of the text will not as well as other fields that are pulled also with a $_GET  and displayed on the page.

Comment: Thanks so much.. after reading I used urlencode() in the sending webpage  and then urldecode() in the receiving page for the variable txt and all works....  Again thank you.. your suggestions were a big help on where to look